# Blank space at the start of one of the tags I'm watching

Tags: support, tags, sponsored-tags

There is a space at the start of the tag I'm watching: [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch).

[image]

Comment: Seems the [icon is not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq2j3.png) for you.

Comment: You have probably blocked `*.imgur.com`. In an earlier revision you have also written _“Sorry it seems I can not put the picture directly, I have to put a link.”_, followed by a link to `ibb.co`, rather than Stack Exchange’s own Imgur subdomain.

Comment: Hm… it’s likely related to your ISP; not unlikely, considering the location set in your user profile is “Beijing, China”.

Comment: @Xufox Ahh, you guys can see the image, right? That makes me feel better.